# Save many to many relationship in datamapper ORM - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-datamapper

I am a beginner. Here I would to ask all of you that how can I save many to many relationship in to the three tables(table A , table A-b , table B)? Now I am trying to save a new record with new ID into table A, and I have some IDs of table B that I want to save them to the middle table A-B depend on ID of table A. If anyone have experiences with this, please kindly share.
Example:

```
$a = new modelA();
$a->name = ‘new name’;
$a->des = ‘something to say’;

$b = new modelB();
$IDs = new array(1,2,3); //IDs of records in table B


$a->save(array($IDs=>$b));
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing ID's is not supported, Datamapper needs objects to be able to relate.

If you have an array of ID's, you can fetch the objects using an where_in() query, and then save the relation using

```
$a->save($b->all);
```

Comment: I just want to save new record into table A and save new record's ID of table A with many IDs of table B into the middle table(table A-B) because table A has many to many relationship with table B.

Answer (score 0):

I have some values which get from post form like:

- 'new name'
- 'new description'
- array('val1','val2','val3')

in my controller I want to save a new record to table A with:
- 'new name'
- 'new description'
and array('val1','val2','val2') I got IDs of them from table B which has many to many with table A(a new record going to save).

So when I save into table A, the IDs of table B also save to middle table A-B with new ID of table A I just save. How to save?